# SQLNCLI10 Provider with windows 8

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb6, sqlncli

I'm facing a trouble with Windows 8.

I've an application in VB6 using SQL Server 2008 through the net with SQLNCLI10 provider, which I always install with `sqlncli10.msi`, but when I tried to install in a PC with Windows 8, I can't... said something it's no more supported.

I use ADO for connection, and the string connection is:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDataBase;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you installing on a 64-bit machine?  If you are, you may need to create a reference directly to the C:\Windows\SysWow64\sqlncli.dll.